# I want to use schema-validation technique (checkSchema) of express validator for validating the body of the request and return any errors

Tags: node.js, express, backend, express-validator

```
router.post(
  "/",
  [
    body("name").isLength({ min: 3 }),
    body("email").isEmail(),
    body("password").isLength({ min: 5 }),
  ],
  (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    res.send(req.body);
  }
);
```

I want to replace the individual parameters checking by another middleware validation function which checks using checkSchema https://express-validator.github.io/docs/api/check-schema#schema as i would be more structured and easier to use .

I tried using the documentation and tutorials but could not find any solution